# What is the ideal projective of empty?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I have a question which is:  What is the ideal projective of empty?
$I_p(\varnothing) = ?$

I think they are all homogeneous polynomials. Would that be correct? If I'm wrong, which one would it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess by $I_p$ you mean the projective version of $I(\cdot)$ in affine case. I will give an answer based on Exercise I.2.3 in Hartshorne.
**2.3.d)** If $\alpha\subseteq S_\bullet$ is a homogeneous ideal with $Z(\alpha)\neq\emptyset$, then $I(Z(\alpha)=\sqrt{\alpha}$.
If we use the Nullstellensatz without worrying the condition, we will have
$$I_p(V_p(I))=\sqrt{I}$$
So we let $I=S_+$ where $S_+$ is the irrevelant ideal of our graded ring $S_\bullet$. Then the Nullstellensatz tells us that
$$I_p(V_p(S_+))=I_p(\emptyset)=\sqrt{S_+}=S_+$$
as $S_+$ is prime, hence radical.
However, $I_p(\emptyset)=S_\bullet=(1)$ as well. This motivates the notion "irrevelant", as by ignoring it, we have the bijection between the set of homogeneous radical ideals of $S_\bullet$ not equal to $S_+$ and the algebraic sets in $\mathbb{P}^n$. Hence the only option left for $I_p(\emptyset)$ is $S_\bullet$ itself.
**Using definition only.**
Since we have
$$I_p(\emptyset):=\{f\in k[x_0,\cdots,x_n]| f \text{ is homogeneous, } f(P)=0\ \forall P\in\emptyset\}$$
As there is no point $P$ in the emptyset, it is vacuously true. Hence all polynomials are there.

Comment: This is overkill, you don't need the Nullstellensatz to determine the ideal - using the definition is enough.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Thank you for pointing out! Hopefully this also means my answer is not wrong! Yes, it is clear if one uses the definition. Here I wish to point out a possible mistake that one might make (myself, for example) when approaching this problem with Nullstellensatz.

Comment: @Mizutsuki I understand much better now, thank you very much for the answer